# Wordpress Links to Posts Not Working After Migration

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks, broken-links

I'm having problem with accessing my blog posts. Ever since i am migrating to new server, the following problem occurs.

At first, the links both to pages and posts are not working. But somehow  i fixed the pages, and now it started working. But the links to posts are not working yet.

Everytime when I clicked on posts, it says error 500. I already checked the `.htaccess` file and used the `Settings > Permalink` back to default but still didn't work. `Mod rewrite` is `active` too, i can access link to pages using permalink.

Can anyone help point where's the problem is?

```
.htaccess file
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

**P.S:** Sorry for my bad grammar, english is not my main language

Comment: 500 server error is caused by the server itself most of the time, have you tried contacting the hosting?

Comment: A 500 error is the webservers way of saying "I have a major problem, but I don't want to say it in public". Look at the error log of the server, there will be a clear message saying what's wrong.

Comment: It's on our own server, we do not rent hosting anymore. The Website itself can be accessed just fine, the products page, the contact us page, the career page. The problem is only to blog posts only. The links won't work

Comment: Ok so I have found something based on the advice to look up at apache2 error log [Fri Jan 08 07:38:22.130290 2016] [:error] [pid 13089] [client 180.244.139.173:55484] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/xxx/single.php on line 101, referer: http://www.domain.com/en/career/

Answer (score 0):

Update .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Configure Permalinks:

Custom Structure : /%postname%/

Please View : https://codex.wordpress.org/File:permalink-settings.png

Comment: I've tried this, and just tried it again. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after checking out the apache error log which points faults on my wordpress theme single.php file, i found out the culprit turns out the "Related News script" injected to my single php file. This makes the whole error 500 whenever I tried to access blog posts.

The script was like this:

```
                    <!-- Related News -->
                    <div class="relatedposts hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    <h3>Artikel Lainnya</h3>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <?php
                        $orig_post = $post;
                        global $post;
                        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

                        if ($tags) {
                        $tag_ids = array();
                        foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
                        $args=array(
                        'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                        'posts_per_page'=>3, // Number of related posts to display.
                        'caller_get_posts'=>1
                        );

                        $my_query = new wp_query( $args );

                        while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $my_query->the_post();
                        ?>

                        <div class="relatedthumb">
                            <a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array('class' => 'img-responsive img-thumbnail',230,170)); ?><br />
                            <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <? }
                        }
                        $post = $orig_post;
                        wp_reset_query();
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Related News-->
```

I have deleted those lines and all problem solved!

Thankies for sharing your advices!